# How to find size of a List of WebElements?

Tags: list, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to find the total number of radio buttons in group1, I tried with the below code, but the system is throwing an error and suggesting me to use getSize() instead of Size().

```
System.out.println(dr.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name= 'group2']")).size());
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findElements()` method and extract the *size* invoking the `size()` method as follows :

```
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name='group2']")).size());
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the radio buttons by path and store them in a list

```
List<WebElement> radioGrp01 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name= 'group1']"));

System.out.println(radioGrp01.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

//WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm");

//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Milk']")).click();

int count =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name='group1']")).size();

System.out.println(count);
for(int i=0;i<count;i++)

{

//driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name='group1']")).get(i).click();

String text=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name='group1']")).get(i).getAttribute("value");

if(text.equals("Cheese"))

{

driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name='group1']")).get(i).click();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Findelement` we dont have `Size()`.

You need to use:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name='group1']")).size();
```